# "power aware design" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What would be a good translation for a power aware design when speaking about an electronic design flow?

> Energiebewusster Entwurf?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

> energiebewusst

is in fact a [German word](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/energiebewusst):

> Energie  nicht vergeudend, sondern sich beim Verbrauch ihrer natürlichen Begrenztheit in besonderem Maße bewusst seiend

I think it is the right word for your sentence even though it's normally used for expressing a "green" approach to something. For example, *energiebewusstes Bauen*.

Answer (score 6):

**Energiebewusstes Design.**

"Design" is commonly used in German, and is more appropriate than "Entwurf" in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

How about **energieorientiertes Design**? "Bewusst" may have a strange esoteric connotation to some ears, especially when used together with "Energie".

Answer (score 0):

Wenn der Entwurf geeignet ist Energie zu sparen, dann

> energiesparender Entwurf

oder, wenn Strom die Energiequelle ist, `stromsparender Entwurf`. 
Ist man sich bewusst, dass der Entwurf zu massig Energievergeudung führen wird, dann ist

> energiebewusster Entwurf

richtig, auch wenn es falsch verstanden wird, weil sich der schlechte Begriff eingebürgert hat. Siehe auch:

```
 F: "Wissen Sie wie spät es ist?"
 A: "Ja."
```

Comment: Das neue an dem Entwurf ist das er erstmalig darauf ausgelegt ist bei späteren Produkt Energie zu sparen. Diese Unterstützung des Entwicklers, macht Ihm den Verbrauch seines fertigen Produktes somit bewusst?

Comment: @eactor: Welchem `ihm`, dem Konsumenten? Ein Gebäude, bei dem die Heizungsrohre ungedämmt außen verlegt werden macht mir den Energieverbrauch viel stärker bewusst.

Comment: Mit Ihm meine ich den Entwickler.

Comment: @eactor: Ich dachte der Entwickler sei es, der zum Power-aware-Design greift, also als erster energiebewußt sein muss, um es dann anderen zu vermitteln.